# Mailbox Name Not Allowed. Sender Address Rejected. Not Logged In

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, vb.net-2010

Tried a lot to identify the root cause of this error but totally failed.  Any suggestion will be highly helpful.

[image: Error Message]

```
Try
    Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
    Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
    Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(txtFrom.Text, txtPassword.Text)
    Smtp_Server.Port = cmbPort.Text

    Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = cbxSSL.Checked
    Smtp_Server.Host = cmbHost.Text

    e_mail = New MailMessage()
    e_mail.From = New MailAddress(txtFrom.Text)
    e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text)
    e_mail.Subject = "Auto Email"
    e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
    e_mail.Body = "Hi, This is test mail."

    Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
    MsgBox("Mail Sent")


Catch error_t As Exception
    MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: Do u need a domain name to be included with the username...e.g. username@fqdn

Comment: User Name refers to from address right? (txtFrom.Text) Currently I am having the full address only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue on my own.

Assume that your mail id is : "mymail@mymaildomain.com"

In SMTP Credentials just mention the "mymail" ignoring the @ and rest of the email parts.

```
Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("mymail", txtPassword.Text)
```

Mention your full email address in From Address only.

```
e_mail.From = New MailAddress("mymail@mymaildomain.com")
```

Hope this will help someone who encounters the same issue in future.